# Upload a file to Lumen API from Angular2 app

Tags: angular, lumen

I have an API (Lumen) which expects a file-field in the body.

With Postman I simply can parse a file to the API and Lumen saves it on the server.

But how to upload a file to the API with Angular2? At the moment I am using HTTP to do post-requests.

```
this.http.post(ENDPOINT, body, options).....
```

Comment: I'd like to help you but have a time understanding the question. Can you try to clear up the spelling and add some code examples? The request information from Postman would be a great start!

Comment: @MaartenBicknese maybe you can understand it now? Simply want to upload a file from my angular2 app to lumen api...

Comment: that didn't help too much. I urge you to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Hi Rakete, how exactly do you want to pass a file from your angular app?Do you want to have a file input element on the page from where the user selects the file and the file gets uploaded to the server?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following.

Template:

```
<input type="file" 
        id="file"
        (change)="onInputFile($event)">
```

Code:

```
onInputFile(event){
    let file = event.target.files[0];

    uploadFile(file).then(
       (res:any) => { console.log(res);},
       (error:any) => { console.log(error);}
    )
}

uploadFile(file, url) {
    return new Promise((success, reject) => {
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('myFile', file);

        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.onload = function(){
            if(this.status == 200){
                success(this.response);
            } else {
                reject(this.statusText);
            }
        }

        xhr.onerror = function(){
            reject(this.statusText);
        }

        xhr.open('POST', url, true);
        xhr.send(formData);
    });
}
```

Hope it would help.

**UPDATE:**

> there is a "angular-way" to do it with the http-class...

Angular2 documentation say: the POST body must actually be a string. You can try convert a file to base64 and post it.

```
uploadFile(file, url){
        let req = this.http;
        let reader = new FileReader();

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);

        reader.onload = function() {
            req.post(url, reader.result).toPromise();
        };

        reader.onerror = function(error) {
            console.log('Error: ', error);
        };   
    }
```

Comment: Yes, this works. This is the way I do it at the moment. But I hoped there is a "angular-way" to do it with the http-class...

Answer (score 1):

There had been an issue with the content-header type requests but now it has been resolved.
You can refer here to these links
Github - https://github.com/angular/http/issues/69
 and
         https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/7310/files

Comment: Can you give an small code example? Is it possible since this feature to pass a file to the http.post() function?